# 5.51.3 to 5.54.0 - "DB_Error: DB Error: no such field in unknown on line unknown" for non-admins when running reports

Tags: civimember, upgrade, civireport, database, permissions

We recently upgraded our CiviCRM instance from 5.51.3 to 5.54.0 to resolve some of the bugs that 5.54.0 resolves.

Since then, *non administrator* users are not able to run any reports, and they get a generic DB Error. I see this error in the logs:

```
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: no such field in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 944

DB_Error: DB Error: no such field in unknown on line unknown
```

When I look at the last line in the debug info, I see this:

```
** Unknown column 'cgroup_civireport.id' in 'where clause']
```

Since anyone who is an admin can run this report, I'm assuming that this error relates to something permissions based. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: As requested by Demerit, I turned on Debugging and Backtrace and added the full error/backtrace here: https://gist.github.com/benrfairless/924dd3b88f4e829a5038e00fea1fe82c

Comment: cgroup is an alias for civicrm_group in reports, so something to do with groups. Do you have the full stack trace in the log?

Comment: I've added this here: https://gist.github.com/benrfairless/924dd3b88f4e829a5038e00fea1fe82c

Comment: Ok thanks. So /public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/au.org.australian-democrats.austdem is obviously a custom extension - I think you need to look at the code in that extension.